# Separability implies flatness, in a special case

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

A nice theorem of Wang, Corollary 9 of [A Jacobian criterion for separability](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869380902331/1-s2.0-0021869380902331-main.pdf?_tid=8e133268-146e-11e5-b228-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1434490256_5b2df6a70da26a62dffac0cd6067a016), says the following:

> Let $B=A[z]=A[Z]/(h(Z))$. If $B$ is a separable algebra over $A$, then $B$ is a flat module over $A$. ($A$ and $B$ are commutative rings with identity.)

I have a problem in understanding his proof, and therefore asks for someone to help with the proof.

I do not know why his first argument is true, namely: "It follows from Corollary 8 that the ideal of $A$ generated by the coefficients of $h(Z)$ is the unit ideal of $A$".

It seems to me that from Corollary 8 only follows that the ideal of $B$ generated by the coefficients of $h(Z)$ is the unit ideal of $B$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to write down what means that $h'(z)$ is invertible in $B$ and then lift the relation to $A[Z]$?

Comment: I was lazy enough to lift the relation to $A[Z]$. I will now check this.

Comment: It takes less time than posting the question.

Comment: I must admit you are right :)

Comment: Just to be sure (I hope I am not wrong): In the relation in $A[Z]$ we send $Z$ to $0$ and get that $a_0$ is invertible in $A$, and therefore the ideal of $A$ generated by the coefficients of $h(Z)=a_nZ^n+\ldots+a_1Z+a_0$ equals $A$. (Again the argument about the universal property does the work..I do not mind that you will write an answer and I will accept it; but you don't have to, only if you wish).

Comment: I had a stupid error in my calculation: In the derivative of $h(Z)$ I wrote $a_1Z$ instead of $a_1$; that's why $a_1$ disappeared, and I got $a_0$ invertible. But nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(Z)=a_nZ^n+\cdots+a_1Z+a_0\in A[Z]$. Since $h'(z)$ is invertible in $A[z]$ there is $f(z)\in A[z]$ such that $h'(z)f(z)=1$, that is, $h'(Z)f(Z)-1\in(h(Z))$ hence there is $g(Z)\in A[Z]$ with $$h'(Z)f(Z)-1=h(Z)g(Z).$$
Now if $Z\mapsto 0$ we get $a_1f(0)-1=a_0g(0)$, that is $a_0(-g(0))+a_1f(0)=1$ which gives $(a_0,a_1)=A$.